# Decreasing sequence in a normed space

Tags: normed-spaces

Consider by $p\geq 1$ the set $l^p=\{(x_n):x_n\in\mathbb{R},\,\,\sum |x_n|^p<\infty\}$. If defined  by $x\in l^1$ $$||x||_p=\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|^p\right)^{1/p}$$ How to prove that the sequence $(||x||_p)_{p\geq 1}$ is decreasing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $x\in \ell^p$ with $\|x\|_p = 1$, $q > p$. Then we have $|x_n| \le 1$ for all $n$, that is $|x_n|^q \le |x_n|^p$, hence 
$$ \|x\|_q^q = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|^q \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|^p = 1 $$
This gives $\|x\|_q \le 1$.
If $x \in \ell^p$ is arbitrary, let $x' = x/\|x\|_p$. We have $\|x'\|_p = 1$, by the above $\|x'\|_q = \|x/\|x\|_p\|_q \le 1$, therefore $\|x\|_q \le \|x\|_p$. So $p\mapsto \|x\|_p$ is decreasing.

Comment: martini why if $\|x\|_p = 1$ then  $|x_n| \le 1$ for all $n$?

Comment: As $|x_n| = (|x_n|^p)^{1/p}\le (\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_k|^p)^{1/p} = \|x\|_p$.

Comment: Ok. Thanks martini.